# How can I add an external folder to source code using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-13

My project is setup in a way that I have to include an external folder which holds some property files that store DB access properties which is required to part of the Java code base to run the JUNITS. Eclipse has an option under 'Run Configuration' where you can add such a folder to the class path and is available as 'Bootstrap Entries'. I am using Intellij and have not been able to figure how to provide that rather than adding this code part of the code base under JUNIT source.

[image]

Comment: I think that this setting must be IDE independent somehow. Otherwise how to build your project with CI tools, like Jenkins or from a simple command line? I suggest you solve this problem at the lowest level.

Comment: Thanks @zappee. This is how the things are setup and there are many other applications which all need the same setup to run JUNITS.